# iOS building a feed of unseen images

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

My app needs a feed of unseen images. I am planning to do this with a `UITableViewController` combined with `NSFetchedResultsController`.

When the user visits this feed, he will be presented with images that he has not seen before. As he scrolls through the table, the images that he has scrolled through would be considered to have been seen.

Naturally, I thought of setting the fetchedResultsController's request to be looking for images with the predicate `"seen = 0"`. My UITableViewController's `didEndDisplayingCell` will simply mark the item as seen.

However, this is not ideal because `NSFetchedResultsController` will tell the tableView to delete the rows as they no longer exist within the fetched results controller.

**I would like my users to be able to scroll back and still see these images. These images should only disappear the next time the user uses the app.**

Can someone recommend a clever way to go about doing this?

Comment: Someone recommended me to use an NSSet to store the list of seen items and update them only at viewDidDisappear. The only problem with this is that viewDidDisappear will also be fired when the user change tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I suggest you to do:

1 - Create an NSMutableArray where you can add some id of the cell/picture

2 - In your viewDidLoad of your UITableViewController add the following

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                         selector: @selector(handleEnteredBackground:) 
                                             name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                           object: nil];
```

3 - Implement the method `handleEnteredBackground:`, so when your app will enter the background state, you  you enumerate your array and mark all the objects that match the NSFetchedResultsController objects with seen = 1.